# How to achieve Time series, zoomable highcharts on ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I'd like to achieve time series, zoomable highcharts,like following picture, on ruby.
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series
[image]

I've achieved the following line chart using [lazy_high_charts](https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts)  However I have no idea how to get the time series chart. Could you tell me how to solve the problem?

```
def show
  @graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
    f.title(text: 'A/B Price')
    f.xAxis(categories: @date_array)
    f.plotOptions(line: {marker: {enabled: false}})
    f.series(name: 'A/B', data: @rate_array)
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the seconds graph?

Comment: I'd like to fill color under the line.
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) `f.xAxis(categories: @date_array)` - creates an array of categories, while you need `f.xAxis(:type=> "datetime")` instead. Also, `@rate_array` should be an array of arrays, like this:

```
[ [date_1, value_1], [date_2, value_2], ... ]
```

2) Change type from `line` to `area`, for example:

```
f.series(:type=> "area", :name=> 'A/B', :data=> @rate_array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some `area` attributes to your `plotOptions`. A very simple example would be:

```
f.plotOptions(line:{marker: {enabled: false}}, area: {fillColor: '#000000'})
```

A more complex example is link on http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-time-series:

```
area: {
    fillColor: {
        linearGradient: {
            x1: 0,
            y1: 0,
            x2: 0,
            y2: 1
        },
        stops: [
            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
        ]
    },
    marker: {
        radius: 2
    },
    lineWidth: 1,
    states: {
        hover: {
            lineWidth: 1
        }
    },
    threshold: null
}
```

Comment: Thx @spickermann. But,  `f.plotOptions(line:{marker: {enabled: false}}, area: {fillColor: '#000000'})` didn't return filled area.

Answer (score 1):

By writing as following, I've got the chart like attached picture.

```
@graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.title(text: 'A/B')
  f.xAxis(categories: @date_array)
  f.yAxis(title: {text: 'Exchange rate'})
  f.chart(
    type: "area",
    zoomType: 'x'
  )
  f.plotOptions(
    area: {
        fillColor: {
            linearGradient: {
                x1: 0,
                y1: 0,
                x2: 0,
                y2: 1
            },
            stops: [
              [0, "rgb(255, 255, 255)"],
              [1, "rgb(240, 240, 255)"]
            ]
        },
        marker: {
            radius: 1
        },
        lineWidth: 1,
        states: {
            hover: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        },
        threshold: nil
    }
  )
  f.series(name: 'A/B', data: @rate_array)
```

[image]